# mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'tudor'@'<ipv6 ip>' (using password: YES) PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I want to connect to my database with phpmyadmin
When I try to connect I get

```
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'tudor'@'<ipv6 ip>' (using password: YES)
```

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPcvS.png)

My Config

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Node 3';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'n3sql.tudor0b.xyz';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/* SSL */
$cfg['ForceSSL']= false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca'] = '/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca_path'] = '/etc/mysql/ssl/';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ciphers'] = 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_key'] = '/etc/mysql/ss1/server-key.pem';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_cert'] = '/etc/mysql/ss1/server-cert.pem';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_verify'] = true;
```

My dns resolves to an ipv6 address, my MariaDB IP
When I use mysql workbench to connect to my db it working fine, ssl is working, 0 problems

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
phpMyAdmin: 5.2.1
MariaDB: 10.6.12
PHP: 8.2
My vps has 3 ipv6 ips
And 1 ipv4 local ip
```

I thought that it would work with external ip, because in the docs it said that it would work
I've tried with my dns and ip
My ssl certificates are accessibles by phpmyadmin, I've done that using `chmod 777 /etc/mysql/ssl/`

EDIT: If I use my ipv6 mariadb ip it says `mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for 2a01 failed: Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: tudor user has access to this server from any network or you have assigned specific network rule

Comment: any network (%)

Comment: `/etc/mysql/ss1` in code, != `/etc/mysql/ssl` as path?

Comment: User authentication always takes place after a secure TLS connection has been established. Client sends user credentials (username and password) decrypted after TLS handshake succeeded to the server. So the problem is not your TLS configuration, but the failing authentication. Since you didn't provide any details (CREATE USER, Server errorlog) one can use only his crystal ball to find out a possible reason.